# Monotonicity of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Assume $f(x,y)$ is twise continuously differentiable and the derivative with respect to both arguments (i.e., $x$ and $y$) are monotone in the sense that the following holds true for any $x,x'\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $x\neq x'$:
$$(x'-x)(D_xf(x,x')-D_xf(x,x))>0~\textrm{and}$$
$$(x'-x)(D_yf(x',x)-D_yf(x,x))>0~\textrm.$$
Suppose now we have $$f(x,x')-f(x,x)>0.$$
Can we prove that the following statement is true:
$f(x',x')-f(x',x)\geq0?$

Comment: you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kachurovskii%27s_theorem

Comment: @ac15 Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Let $p=x'-x.$ Define

\begin{align*}
I_1&=f(x',x)-f(x,x)=\int_0^1 p\cdot D_xf(x+tp,x) dt\\
I_2&=f(x,x')-f(x,x)=\int_0^1 p\cdot D_yf(x,x+tp) dt\\
I_3&=f(x',x')-f(x,x)=\int_0^1 [p\cdot D_xf(x+tp,x+tp)+p\cdot D_yf(x+tp,x+tp) ]dt
\end{align*}

The monotonicity conditions give
\begin{align*}
(-tp)\cdot (D_xf(x+tp,x) - D_xf(x+tp,x+tp))&>0\\
(-tp)\cdot (D_yf(x,x+tp) - D_yf(x+tp,x+tp))&>0
\end{align*}
and hence $I_1+I_2<I_3.$ Rearranging and cancelling $f(x,x)$ terms, $f(x',x')-f(x',x)>f(x,x')-f(x,x),$ which is positive by assumption.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!