# Equivalent condition for the following monotone-like condition for multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuously twice differentiable function.

I am considering the following condition (1) on $f$: For any $x,x'\in\mathbb R^n$,

If it is either $f(x,x')>f(x,x)$ or $f(x',x)>f(x,x)$, we should have $f(x',x')\geq\max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x)\}$.

Equivalently,

$$\tag{1}\max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x)\}>f(x,x)\Rightarrow f(x',x')\geq\max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x)\},~\forall x,x'\in\mathbb R^n.$$

**My question is : Is there an equivalent condition to (1)?**

One possibility is that the monotonicity of partial derivatives is related to some of the inequalities in (1).

More specifically, let the following inequalities be true for all $x,x'\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $x\neq x'$:
$$(x'-x)(D_xf(x,x')-D_xf(x,x))>0~\textrm{and}$$
$$(x'-x)(D_yf(x',x)-D_yf(x,x))>0~\textrm.$$
According to my previous question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834991/monotonicity-of-a-multivariate-function)) this monotonicity implies the following:  $$f(x,x')>f(x,x)\Rightarrow f(x',x')>f(x',x).$$

We have the relationship between $f(x',x')-f(x',x)$ and $f(x,x')-f(x,x)$. But what is missing to answer (1) is the relationship between $f(x',x')-f(x,x')$ and $f(x,x')-f(x,x)$, that I cannot find from my previous question. Any condition that reveals the relationship between $f(x',x')-f(x,x')$ and $f(x,x')-f(x,x)$?

Any comment and answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent condition is: For all $x,x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\iff \left[
\begin{array}{ll}
    \max\{f(x',x'),f(x,x) \} \ge \max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x) \}  > \min\{f(x',x'),f(x,x)  \} \\
 \min\{f(x',x'),f(x,x) \} \ge \max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x) \}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where the right bracket means "either ..or".

I don't know whether these conditions have a name.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If it is the either-or case, can we equivalently say "It is not the case that we have $\max\{f(x',x'),f(x,x)\}<\max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x)\}$"? Or, "We should have $\max\{f(x',x'),f(x,x)\}\geq\max\{f(x,x'),f(x',x)\}$"?

Comment: @Andeanlll We can say: at least one of the two statements must hold true.